# Ant sqlplus report error

Tags: ant, sqlplus

I am invoking SQLPlus through Ant's exec command. I want to catch the errors that SQLPlus will throw and then halt the rest of the build.

However SQLPlus exits gracefully, that is when an error occurs it will exit SQLPlus with a return of 0 hence Ant thinks SQLPlus has successfully executed.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one http://incanto.sourceforge.net/usage-sqlplus.html .

There is an option "failOnError" and I suppose that is what you want.

Comment: I don't want to use Incanto as this doesn't seem industry standard

Comment: even if you don't want to use it - you always can check how it is implemented there and reuse their approach.